# Java application development (Desktop and Web)

Tags: java

I am new to java application development.I have a project which is successfully created using wpf as a windows application.Now i need to develop this project in java to support windows,linux,mac os,etc.I need to develop as a web application. Later i need to do it as desktop based that supports all os also.

So My question is, Is it possible to develop this application both desktop and web compatible ?

If it is possible what technologies of java programming i need to use? (eg. springs, ...)

Kindly apologize for my bad english.

Comment: make a stand alone desktop application and for web access you can make HTTP calls from your application

Answer (score 3):

Of course everything is possible. Depending on your needs, look for Dynamic web projects or static web projects this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) might help to begin.

Comment: how can i run jsp and servlet in standalone application ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with basic tutorials for servlet and JSP's then go for spring or other frameworks
[SEE THIS](https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=o1lNUszrB4yJrAe0mYDYCw#q=simple%20jsp%20servlet%20example%20using%20eclipse%20)

Comment: how can i run jsp and servlet in standalone application ?

Comment: You can call them by creating services.

Answer (score 1):

Yea java supports for both u can connect via HTTP request/response

Using J2EE technologies, It will help to develop your application according to your requirement. & You can re-use lot of useful methods from above technologies as your needy requirement.

First divide you application through layers like Front-end, BussinessLogic , DataAccessLayer. then takes frameworks & patterns according to your layers

Example:

```
     Frontend- Struts 2

     BussinessLogic - EJB

     DataAccessLayer - Hibernate/JDBC
```

You can integrate those thing with spring using dependence-injection